# Hide a Column in datagrid, without setting column.visble=false

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeRead" ItemStyle-Width="25%"  HeaderText="TimeRead" SortExpression="TimeRead" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ItemStyle-Width="45%" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" ReadOnly="True" Display="none" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
```

How Can I hide the Email column in the datagrid., I dont Want to use column.visible property. How Can i hide it using css properties or anyother method. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075813/hide-a-datagrid-column-with-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" ItemStyle-Width="45%" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
   <ItemStyle CssClass="boundfield-hidden" />
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="boundfield-hidden" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

That's how you add a CSS class directly to the bound field.

Now, in your css file, just add the following:

```
.boundfield-hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Header(Email) is still visible, but the column below it is invisible. How to hide the header

Comment: @Mano add <HeaderStyle CssClass="boundfield-hidden" /> above or below the ItemStyle line.